# How to simulate water balloons in a bag?

Tags: physics

I checked to blender cloth pressure documentation, I checked other questions on this website and also YT videos.

I'm trying to get a bag filled with water balloons. The two water balloons are subdivided cubes with a *Cloth* and a *Collision* modifier. The cloth is a subdivided plane, also with a *Cloth* and a *Collision* modifier on it. My progress can be seen in the image.[image: test with 2 water balloons]

How can I do it right? At the moment it takes a lot to test different types and tweaks of parameters. Is there like a website with cloth recipes?

How can I achieve this in an optimal manner?

here is the blend file

[image]

Comment: There's no cookbook, because it's too dependent on what your topology is (and your topology here looks much denser than I would use.)  If I wanted to do a water balloon in a bag, I would use cloth physics, with both balloon and bag in a single object; self-collision, pressure, and fluid density would be essential parameters.

Comment: maybe share your blendfile, so we can check it out

Comment: I uploaded the blend :) many thanks for trying to help a newb

Comment: What is the expected animation? Should the two balls fall down, get caught by the cloth and bounce softly up and down?

Comment: We played a lot with water balloons when young. The expected outcome would be the bag to contain all balloons and the balloons to shape themselves in a realistic manner around the containing bag. So there is a lot of collision going on and I fear that what I want to achieve is impossible.

Comment: Also I want to thank the person who edited my question and made it more readable. I now learned how to ask questions a little better and give out more details on my problem. Great help!

Comment: Have you tried to un-subdivide the plane and the balls 2x? Then use the preset *Rubber* for the cloth settings for the balls.